# ALB health check failing with 502 error with my terraform config

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-application-load-balancer

Hi i'm beginner and i'm trying to play with VPC on AWS and Terraform and i'm stuck on ALB health check issue

[image]

I have 2 az with a ec2 and a webserver on each ec2 my goal is to setup the load balancer and be able to be redirected on one of my ec2, my ec2 are on a private subnet and a Nat Gatway and elastic IP

I've tried to setup a bastion host to check on the ssh if my ec2 was well link to internet and the answer is yes

this is my setup terraform : ( baybe there is an obvious error that i haven't seen )

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  shared_credentials_file = "./aws/credentials"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  enable_dns_support = true

  tags = {
    Name = "my-vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "main" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "my-internet-gateway"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_a" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.1.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1a"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "my-public-a-subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_b" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.2.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1b"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true

  tags = {
    Name = "my-public-b-subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_a" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.3.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1a"

  tags = {
    Name = "my-private-a-subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_b" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "10.0.4.0/24"
  availability_zone       = "us-east-1b"

  tags = {
    Name = "my-private-b-subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_nat_gateway" "main" {
  allocation_id = aws_eip.main.id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public_a.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "main" {
  vpc = true
  tags = {
    Name = "my-nat-gateway-eip"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
  name        = "my-security-group"
  description = "Allow HTTP and SSH access"
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "my-security-group"
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_a" {
    ami = "ami-0c2b8ca1dad447f8a"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.private_a.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]

    tags = {
      Name = "my-ec2-a"
    }

    key_name = "vockey"
    user_data = file("user_data.sh")
}

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_b" {
    ami = "ami-0c2b8ca1dad447f8a"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    subnet_id = aws_subnet.private_b.id
    vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]

    tags = {
      Name = "my-ec2-b"
    }

    key_name = "vockey"
    user_data = file("user_data.sh")
}

resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami = "ami-0c2b8ca1dad447f8a"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.public_a.id
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.main.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "my-bastion"
  }

  key_name = "vockey"
  user_data = file("user_data_bastion.sh")
}

resource "aws_alb" "main" {
  name = "my-alb"
  internal = false
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.main.id]
  subnets = [aws_subnet.public_a.id, aws_subnet.public_b.id]

  tags = {
    Name = "my-alb"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group" "ec2" {
  name = "my-alb-target-group"
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "my-alb-target-group"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main.id
  }

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_nat_gateway.main.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "my-private-route-table"
  }

}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_a.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_b.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private.id
}

resource "aws_route_table" "public" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.main.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "My Public Route Table"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_a.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "public_b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_b.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.public.id
}


resource "aws_alb_listener" "main" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_alb.main.arn
  port = "80"
  protocol = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.ec2.arn
    type = "forward"
  }
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "ec2_a" {
  target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.ec2.arn
  target_id = aws_instance.ec2_a.id
  port = 80
}

resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "ec2_b" {
  target_group_arn = aws_alb_target_group.ec2.arn
  target_id = aws_instance.ec2_b.id
  port = 80
}
```

Comment: Is there anything running on port 80 on the EC2 instances?

Comment: Yes the web server is running on the port 80 inside the EC2 instances

Comment: Can you verify that for sure by logging in to the instances? Or you already know that is true?

Comment: It was the case but i killed the webserver and i still have the same issue :/ i also trie to do the health check on 8080

Comment: It cannot work if you kill the web server? Why would you do that? Where would ALB forward the requests then? Currently it seems you do not have a Security Group defined for EC2 instances and for ALB, but only one which you attach to both. I would suggest creating a new one for the instances in the private subnet and allow ingress traffic from the ALB Security Group and all egress traffic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't have a `health_check` block on the `aws_alb_target_group` resource. Try adding something like this:

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group" "ec2" {
  name = "my-alb-target-group"
  port = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.main.id

  health_check {
    path = "/"
    matcher = "200"
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "my-alb-target-group"
  }
}
```

Also, make sure that the HTTP services on your EC2 instances are listening and accepting connections on port 80. You should be able to `curl http://<ec2 ip address>` with a 200 response.